# Trouble connecting to PostgreSQL in python with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

I am having problems connecting to my database through postgreSQL3 version 9.5. However, after running the code below:

```
import psycopg2 as p

con = p.connect("dbname ='dvdrental' user = 'myusername' host ='localhost' password ='somepassword'")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from title")
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

I get this error message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused 
(0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

For background information, I accidentally downloaded the newest version of PostgreSQL, and it connected to the part 5432. I need it to connect to PostgreSQL port 5433. I do not know how to do that. How can I solve this DB problem? Is this a PostgreSQL problem or a python problem?

Comment: If you installed a new version: the new version comes with  a default `postgres.conf` file that only listens on the unix-domain-socket, not localhost or any other ip socket.

Comment: You can force connection over the unix-domain socket by specifying its directory instead of the hostname: `host ='/tmp'` (its default location, but often somewhere in `/var/...` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the listen adresses of postgres, using `netstat` (from the shell):

---

```
plasser@pisbak$ netstat -nl |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9002     /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
plasser@pisbak$
```

---

If nothing shows up, Postgres is *not* listening on port 5432.

Answer (score 2):

what if you add `port = '5433'` to your `p.connect` line?

```
import psycopg2 as p

con = p.connect("dbname ='dvdrental' user = 'myusername' host ='localhost' password ='somepassword' port='5433'")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from title")
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I just tried that, and I get this following error:


'psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "'port"'

Comment: That is strange.  `port` is one of the [basic connection parameter](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html).

Comment: Maybe you could try passing a set of keyword arguments, rather than a connection string.  i.e. `con = p.connect(dbname="dvdrental", user = "myusername", host ="localhost", password ="somepassword", port="5433")`

Comment: Ah I got it to work finally. It was the username that threw me off. Thanks everyone!